# Terminal description & keyboard layout and font

Tags: linux

I know that there is a `term` variable pointing to the appropriate `terminfo` description describing current terminal settings. My question is where in the `terminfo` descriptor (displaying by just `terminfo` cmd) are the current keyboard layout & font defined (which we can be set by `loadkeys` & `setfont`).

Answer (score 1):

terminfo doesn't define *keyboard layout*, but does list the values of *special keys* (function-keys, cursor-keys and some keypad-keys) which are commonly found on terminal keyboards.

The key names (shown in the output of [`infocmp`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html) as names beginning with **`k`**) are not the same as those used for [`loadkeys`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/loadkeys.1.html).  Some are *similar*, e.g., `F11` for `kf11`, but not all.

Finally, terminfo doesn't help (much) with the font, since it only tells (sometimes...) how to switch between fonts, e.g., rarely-used selections on the Linux console.

Comment: So how & where the `keyboard layout` and `font` is defined for use with particular terminal when we switch by `ALT+Fx`?

Comment: So am i right that the _keyboard layout_ and _font_ are set globally for all the virtual consoles in one place?

Comment: The question asked how this could be done with terminfo.  You might ask another question on how those features could be configured, but the answers would have be be in terms of whether it's X or console, and what distribution (since standardization is poor).